# Undoing a mercurial rebase

Tags: mercurial, rebase

I've done a rebase on my local repository, and it's gone wrong. How do I come back from it?

#### Before the rebase

```
@  225:c5eb9b47e19a Task #1 modified due to comment by peers
|
| o  224:7a1964c6b694 WIP on Task #2 depending on Task #1
| |
| o  223:eb5a2ce5ef36 Task #1 sent for peer review
|/
o  222:d18063b01959 Remote tip
```

#### The unfortunate rebase

Coming from a git world, I'm used to rebase things. That may have been my mistake.

```
$ hg rebase -r224
merging some_file
3 files to edit
saved backup bundle to /path/to/repo/.hg/strip-backup/7a1964c6b694-backup.hg
```

#### After the rebase

```
@  224:c5eb9b47e19a Task #1 modified due to comment by peers
|
| o  223:eb5a2ce5ef36 Task #1 sent for peer review
|/
o  222:d18063b01959 Remote tip
```

```
$ hg diff
# nothing
$ hg st -amdr
# nothing
$ hg update --clean 7a1964c6b694
abort: unknown revision '7a1964c6b694'!
```

I'v lost my work commited as *WIP on Task #2 depending on Task #1*: it isn't in `c5eb9b47e19a` (I must have messed while merging), and the original commit is gone (is it?).

How do I cancel / revert my rebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get "WIP on Task #2 depending on Task #1" back

```
hg up 223
hg unbundle /path/to/repo/.hg/strip-backup/7a1964c6b694-backup.hg
```

Get opposite of "WIP on Task #2 depending on Task #1"

```
hg revert --all -r 223
hg commit -m opposite of WIP on Task #2 depending on Task #1
```

Apply opposite of "WIP on Task #2 depending on Task #1" to undo the merge

```
hg update 224
hg rebase -r 225
```